# Почему не изменяется размер виджета при растяжении экрана?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlayout, виджет

Пишу большое приложение. Столкнулся с проблемой: большое количество компонентов находится в контейнерах и при изменении экрана сами не меняются.

Решил попробовать через дополнительную переменную с помощью слота `resizeEvent()` изменять размеры виджетов, но все равно не работает.

В чем моя ошибка?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(400,300)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.w = self.size().width()
        self.h = self.size().height()

        self.text_ed = QTextEdit()
        self.text_ed.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(55,55,55)")
        self.text_ed.setFixedSize(200,200)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addStretch(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.text_ed)
        self.hbox.addStretch(0)

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        width = self.size().width()
        height = self.size().height()

        dif_w = width / self.w
        dif_h = height / self.h

        self.text_ed.setFixedSize(int(200*dif_w),int(200*dif_h))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)
Система компоновки *Qt* предоставляет простой и эффективный способ
автоматического упорядочивания дочерних виджетов внутри виджета,
чтобы гарантировать, что они эффективно используют доступное пространство.

*Qt* включает набор классов управления компоновкой, которые используются для
описания компоновки виджетов в пользовательском интерфейсе приложения.
Эти layouts автоматически позиционируют и изменяют размер виджетов,
когда объем доступного для них места изменяется, гарантируя,
что они последовательно расположены и пользовательский интерфейс
в целом остается пригодным для использования.

Все подклассы `QWidget` могут использовать макеты для управления своими дочерними элементами. Функция `QWidget::setLayout()` применяет макет к виджету.

Когда макет установлен для виджета таким образом, он берет на себя следующие задачи:

- Позиционирование дочерних виджетов
- Разумные размеры по умолчанию для окон
- Обработка изменения размера
- Автоматические обновления при изменении содержимого:

  - Размер шрифта, текст или другое содержимое дочерних виджетов
  - Скрытие или отображение дочернего виджета
  - Удаление дочерних виджетов

Вам надо изучить раздел [**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Если у вас проблемы с размещением виджетов, то вам следует задавать более конкретные вопросы и приводить конкретный контейнер(ы) с виджетами,
которыми вы их заполняете и показывать на изображении как вы из хотите разместить и как они (виджеты) должны себя вести при изменение окна.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        
# ???        для чего вы сдесь это делаете, окно еще не заполнено. 
# ???        Что вы хотите показать? 
# ???        self.showMaximized()

# окно еще не отрисовано и его размер в этом месте 640х480       
#        self.w = self.size().width()
#        self.h = self.size().height()
#        print(f'self.w = {self.w} , self.h = {self.h}') #

        self.text_ed = QTextEdit('''<h1>Это QTextEdit<\h1>
<h2>Почему не изменяется размер виджета при растяжении экрана? PyQt5<\h2>
<br><br>
<h2>Размер виджета QTextEdit - очень даже изменяется.<\h2>
        ''')
        self.text_ed.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
            color: rgb(55, 55, 255);
        """)
# ??? зачем
#        self.text_ed.setFixedSize(200, 200)

        # попробуйте заеомментировать строку ниже
        self.text_ed.setMaximumSize(400, 400) # просто ограничил размер виджета

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
# ???        self.hbox.addStretch(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.text_ed)
# ???        self.hbox.addStretch(0)

    # просто оставил для статистики
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        width = self.size().width()
        height = self.size().height()
        print(f'\nwidth  = {width}  , height = {height}') #
        print(f'text_ed.rect = {self.text_ed.rect()}') #
        
#        dif_w = width // 2     #self.w
#        dif_h = height // 2    #self.h
#        self.text_ed.setFixedSize(int(200*dif_w), int(200*dif_h))
#        self.text_ed.setFixedSize(dif_w, dif_h)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()

# или так    
    window.showMaximized()
# или так    
#    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]